# Global Authority for Blacklisting IPs

Tags: .htaccess, security, blacklist

I know that there are few common ways to block `spam` and attacking IPs (such as `deny in htaccess`). Additional to that, we could get a huge list of IPs to block from misc sites such as :

1. http://www.okean.com/antispam/cnkr_htaccess.txt
2. http://www.stopforumspam.com

However, it looks very inefficient to block all these already known "bad" IPs for every project and all via htaccess or so.

.

So I want to know:

A) if there is any `Global authority` that should `monitor and block` such IPs from the Internet all together for the whole Internet...

B) If there could be any `simple+fast+autoUpdate` `"list"` method (such as used in AdBlockPlus) for the projects (websites) and they will simple load IPs to block on daily basis and block them (while remaining low cost in server delays).

Comment: looking forward for the 1st negative vote :D

Comment: If you are looking for negative votes, why did you post?

Comment: @Jordan thats all you got to say for all I had to write? !!

Comment: It's not a programming question. But, I'm sure someone will try to find out for you.

Comment: @Jordan Its a technical question related to website security. How can you say that its not a programming question??!!

Comment: I disagree. It is more related to IT administration. Try ServerFault.com.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/search?q=blacklist+ip